# How to add and ignore a field for json response

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I'm using RestEasy and hibernate to return response in Jackson.
I have a bean Player having fields: name, id, age, position.

Now, I'm implementing two `GET` rest methods for returing json.

1. `getPlayer()`, which is returning a player: name, id, age, position.
2. `getPlayers()`, which is returning a list of players, but with this list of players, i do not want to return position.

I mean, how can I add a field for one response and ignore it for another response.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Can't you simply null out the position field?

```
@GET
@Path("/players")
public List<Player> getPlayers(){
    List<Player> players = getPlayersFromHibernate();

    for(Player player : players)
        player.setPosition(null);

    return players;
}
```

Comment: this opens you up to introducing a bug if you forget to write the code to null out the field.  use `@JsonIgnore` so you don't have to.

Comment: How will that solve the the OP's requirement "How can I add a field for one response and ignore it for another response." ? Besides, 'forgetting' to do stuff when you code will always cause bugs ;)

Comment: This looks the simplest solution to me, along with adding @JsonIgnore to properties which have to be always ignored. Eiden, have you found any other way to do it? I do not like the way JsonView and JsonFilter can be used to get the same result.

Comment: is this working? 
cuz I think that way too, and I made my unnecessary records null before I send it to the `ObjectMapper` to convert it to JSON. Mapper gives null pointer error. I think it is about sub fields of "product" that I set null. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Of course this is more a workaround than an answer, but as a quick and dirty solution it works in case the JsonIgnore annotation is not available for some other reason (if you have compiled pojo for instance).

Answer (score 18):

You should use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the POJO getter.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html

**Update:**

You need to use interface with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and set it as `@JSONFilter` on your Request mapping.

You can read more about it here:
http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/filtering_json_feeds_from_spring

Comment: that i know, but i want same field to ignore for one reponse and same field to add for another

Comment: as given in the link... i need to make a interface AppDetailFilter(), and use @JsonFilter with the request. but am not getting what should be in interface, and how to use it to ignore diffrent fields for different request.

Comment: This is just kind of marker interface which has no methods. You can configure few interfaces. and then you map each request with this interface.

Answer (score 1):

I am using tomee, to ignore a field in json response `transient` works for me, but i don't know if it is the correct way to go (there is no jackson visible to my application, i just included jee-web api):

Servlet

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class JsonApi {

    @GET
    @Path("testapi")
    public MyObject testApi() {
        return new MyObject("myname", "mycolor");
    }
}
```

Object

```
public class MyObject {

    public MyObject() {
    }

    public MyObject(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String name;

    public transient String color;
}
```

Response

```
{"name":"myname"}
```

Comment: This approach may introduce problems when using persistence, I wouldn't go that way. On the other hand, if you use this object just for data transfer, it should be fine.