# RESTEasy + Jackson: how to exclude fields in the response?

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm migrating my Java web application from servlet-based to JAX-RS. Since I'm using Jboss I'll also use (by default) RESTEasy.

In my servlets I use Jackson to serialize/deserialize JSON; Jackson allows me to filter programatically the inclusion/exclusion of fields, for example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, 
Visibility.ANY);

String[] ignorableFieldNames = { "id", "name" };

FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().
addFilter("f123",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames));

mapper.filteredWriter(filters).writeValueAsString(object);
```

RESTEasy provides Jackson support, but it seems that it is embedded transparently to the developer so I'm not able to get to the low-level to include/exclude fields. Is this feasible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add and ignore a field for json response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892937/how-to-add-and-ignore-a-field-for-json-response)

Comment: @ruffp similar, but not quite a dup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/) to declaratively configure pretty much everything. In your case, `@JsonIgnore` should suffice.

You can use [JSON views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) if you don't want to ignore those fields all the time.

If you can't modify the code of the class in question (say, because it's in a third-party library) [mix-ins have you covered.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

And if you *still* find that you need to access the `ObjectMapper`: [Accessing Jackson Object Mapper in RestEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8498413/139010).

See also: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations

Comment: thanks, the pointer to "Accessing Jackson Object Mapper in RestEasy" did the trick