# Ignore a java bean field while converting to jSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, cxf

Ignore a java bean field while converting to jSON

I am having a java bean and sending JSON as response , In that java bean I want to have
some transient fields , that should not come into JSON .

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "sample")
class Sample{

private String field1;

@XmlTransient
private String transientField;

//Getter and setters

public String toJSON() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    return json;
}

}
```

When I am calling toJSON method I am still getting "transientField" in JSON.

And I have a get rest API that returns this Sample JSON as response.

```
@GET
@Path("/somePath/")
@Produces({"application/json"})
Sample getSample();
```

In this response also I am getting that transient field .
Am I doing something wrong? Please help me to do this .

Comment: Duplicate. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831876/resteasy-jackson-how-to-exclude-fields-in-the-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method 1: use annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties("fieldname") to your POJO

example : @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"fieldTobeIgnored"})

method 2:@JsonIgnore for a specific field that is to be ignored deserializing JSON

Answer (score 2):

Try using `@JsonIgnore` instead.