# How to reduce no. of json fields in response of spring restful services

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

this is the code:

```
public class RestApi_Controller {


@Autowired
public AirportRepo Airport_Repository;

@RequestMapping(value="/airport/{indexid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Master_Airport> getAirportIndexid(@PathVariable int indexid)
{

    return Airport_Repository.findByIndexid(indexid);
  }
 }
```

Can any one help me out using json filter??

Airport Collection contains:

```
private int indexid;
private String airportcode;
private String airportname;
private String code;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add and ignore a field for json response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892937/how-to-add-and-ignore-a-field-for-json-response)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jackson Annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) to achieve this.

Add Jackson dependency or its jars to your code and annotate the fields like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
private int indexid;
private String airportcode;
@JsonIgnore
private String airportname;
private String code;
```

This will ignore `indexid` and `airportname` in the response.

More details can be found [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)

Comment: I got it.Thank you very much :-)