# Best way to deserialize Json with nested objects into Android Room Entity with ForeignKeys

Tags: kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room, json-deserialization, android-room-relation

I have a `Client` api. The json response looks like this:

```
 {
    "clientId": 1,
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "monthlyPaymentAmount": null,
    "person": {
      // Omitted data here
    },
    "paymentType": {
      // Omitted data here
    },
    "deliveryInstructions": null,
    "referralName": null,
    "referralPhoneNumber": null,
    "status": 0,
    "startDate": null,
    "eventDate": null,
  }
```

So, using the [Kotlin data class file from JSON](https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass) to automatically create data classes from the json response, I've got with the following `Client` data class which I've turned into a Room `@Entity` with `ForeignKeys`:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "client",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Account::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("account_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Person::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("person_id", "account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("person_id", "account_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = PaymentType::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("payment_type_id", "account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("payment_type_id", "account_id"),
        ),
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(value = arrayOf("client_id", "account_id"), unique = true)
    ]
)
data class Client(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_id") val clientId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "delivery_notes") val deliveryInstructions: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_date") val eventDate: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "monthly_payment_amount") val monthlyPaymentAmount: Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "payment_type_id") val paymentType: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "person_id") val person: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "referral_name") val referralName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_date") val startDate: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at") val updatedAt: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "synced_at") val syncedAt: Date,
)
```

There's also `PaymentType` and `Person` data classes which I'm omitting, but they do are Room `@Entity`'s as well.

The Room database needs to match the following database structure that has this `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE client
(
    client_id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    account_id             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    updated_at             TEXT    NOT NULL,
    synced_at              TEXT    NOT NULL,
    person_id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    payment_type_id        INTEGER,
    referral_name          TEXT,
    delivery_notes         TEXT,
    status                 INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    monthly_payment_amount REAL,
    start_date             TEXT,
    event_date             TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT client_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT client_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (person_id, account_id) REFERENCES person (person_id, account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT client_fk4 FOREIGN KEY (payment_type_id, account_id) REFERENCES payment_type (payment_type_id, account_id),
    CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id, account_id)
);
```

So, I've a `Converters` class to deserialize the json response into `Client` class as follows:

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun clientToJson(value: Client?): String? = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToClient(value: String): Client = Gson().fromJson(value, Client::class.java)

    @TypeConverter
    fun paymentTypeToJson(value: PaymentType?): String? = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToPaymentType(value: String): PaymentType =
        Gson().fromJson(value, PaymentType::class.java)

    @TypeConverter
    fun objToJsonPerson(value: Person?): String? = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToObjPerson(value: String): Person = Gson().fromJson(value, Person::class.java)

    // Omitted list of converters here
}
```

I'm hesitant if the `client` converter above does correctly creates `PaymentType` and `Person` objects automatically (mostly convinced that no). That's why I would like to know what's the proper way to deserialize a json response with nested objects into Room entities with Foreign Keys?

I'm most confused with Foreing Keys though. What will happen when the converter above tries to parse the `"person": {}` object into the `@ColumnInfo(name = "person_id")` which is of type `Int`? Will it know that it is a `ForeignKey` and will create a `Person::class` automatically? How's the best/proper way to deserialize nested objects ensuring this relation between the tables is properly done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demonstration following on from previous answer**

This a demonstration of inserting a single client based upon some slightly modified entities.

**Account** :-

```
@Entity
data class Account(
    @PrimaryKey
    val account_id: Long? = null,
    val accountName: String   
)
```

**PaymentType**

```
@Entity( primaryKeys = ["payment_type_id","account_id"])
data class PaymentType(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "payment_type_id")
    val paymentTypeId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "account_id")
    val accountId: Long,
    val paymentTypeName: String
)
```

- added accountId (account_id column) to suit Foreign Key constraints in the ClientTable (as per question)
- composite primary key

**Person** (likewise)

```
@Entity( primaryKeys = ["person_id","account_id"])
data class Person(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "person_id")
    val personId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "account_id")
    val accountId: Long,
    val personName: String
)
```

**Client** as suggested

```
data class Client(
    val clientId: Long,
    val deliveryInstructions: String,
    val eventDate: Date,
    val monthlyPaymentAmount: Float,
    val referralName: String,
    val startDate: Date,
    val status: Long,
    val updatedAt: Date,
    val syncedAt: Date,
    val person: Person,
    val paymentType: PaymentType
) {
    fun getClientAsClientTable(): ClientTable {
        return ClientTable(
            this.clientId,
            this.deliveryInstructions,
            this.eventDate,
            this.monthlyPaymentAmount,
            this.paymentType.paymentTypeId,
            this.person.personId,
            this.referralName,
            this.startDate,
            this.status,
            this.updatedAt,
            this.syncedAt
        )
    }
}
```

- ideally id's should be Long rather than Int as they have the potential to overflow an Int. So Long's have been used.

**ClientTable** formally (Client) :-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "client",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Account::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("account_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Person::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("person_id", "account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("person_id", "account_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = PaymentType::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("payment_type_id", "account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("payment_type_id", "account_id"),
        ),
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(value = arrayOf("client_id", "account_id"), unique = true)
    ]
)
data class ClientTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_id") val clientId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "delivery_notes") val deliveryInstructions: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_date") val eventDate: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "monthly_payment_amount") val monthlyPaymentAmount: Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "payment_type_id") val paymentTypeid: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "person_id") val personid: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "referral_name") val referralName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_date") val startDate: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at") val updatedAt: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "synced_at") val syncedAt: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "account_id") var accountId: Long = 1 //????? ADDED
)
```

- NOTE the addition of the accountId

**Converters**

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToLong(date: Date): Long {
        return date.time / 1000 // divided by 1000 to strip milliseconds as easier to handle dates
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateFromLong(dateAsLong: Long): Date {
        return Date(dateAsLong * 1000) // reapply milliseconds
    }
}
```

**AllDao** (as it implies all of them together) :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(account: Account): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(paymentType: PaymentType): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(person: Person): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(clientTable: ClientTable): Long

    @Query("SELECT count(*) >= 1 FROM account WHERE account_id=:accountId")
    abstract fun doesAccountExistByAccountId(accountId: Long): Boolean
    @Query("SELECT count(*) >= 1 FROM paymenttype WHERE account_id=:accountId AND payment_type_id=:paymentTypeId")
    abstract fun doesPaymentTypeExistByAccountIdPaymentTypeId(accountId: Long, paymentTypeId: Long): Boolean
    @Query("SELECT count(*) >= 1 FROM person WHERE account_id=:accountId AND person_id=:personId")
    abstract fun doesPersonExistByAccountIdPersonId(accountId: Long, personId: Long): Boolean

    @Query("")
    @Transaction
    fun insertFromAPIJson(json: String): Long {
        var rv: Long = -1
        val client = Gson().fromJson(json,Client::class.java)
        val clientTable = client.getClientAsClientTable()
        insert(Account(client.person.accountId,"NO NAME"))
        val accountExits = doesAccountExistByAccountId(client.person.accountId)
        insert(PaymentType(client.paymentType.paymentTypeId,client.paymentType.accountId,client.paymentType.paymentTypeName))
        val paymentTypeExists = doesPaymentTypeExistByAccountIdPaymentTypeId(client.paymentType.accountId,client.paymentType.paymentTypeId)
        insert(Person(client.person.personId, client.person.accountId, client.person.personName))
        val personExists = doesPersonExistByAccountIdPersonId(client.person.accountId,client.person.personId)
        if (accountExits && paymentTypeExists && personExists) {
            clientTable.accountId = client.person.accountId
            rv = insert(clientTable)
        }
        return rv
    }
}
```

- Obviously note the **`insertFromAPIJson`** function
- Also note abstract class rather than an interface
- Note the improvised account name (something you will have to determine how to name)

**TheDatabase** the abstract class annotated with @Database including a basic getInstance function :-

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@Database(entities = [Account::class,ClientTable::class,PaymentType::class,Person::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Finally adding the single client from the JSON (again the client is built and the JSON extracted to mimic the API). **MainActivity** :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        /* Create a Client ready to be converted to JSON */
        val clientx = Client(
            clientId = 1,
            deliveryInstructions = "x",
            eventDate = Date(),
            monthlyPaymentAmount = 111.11F, referralName = "Fred", startDate = Date(), status = 1, updatedAt = Date(), syncedAt = Date(),
            Person(10,1,"Bert"), paymentType = PaymentType(20,1,"Credit Card"))

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        dao.insertFromAPIJson(Gson().toJson(clientx))

    }
}
```

**The Result**

Using App Inspection :-

The **Account** has been added :-

[image]

The **PaymentType** has been added :-

[image]

The **Person** has been added :-

[image]

and the **Client** :-

[image]

**Run again**

As expected the data remains the same due to onConflict IGNORE

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain everything so well and elaborate this example. I think my doubts got solved with the past answer, however, the way to go was still somehow unclear to me until this one explanation with the `dao`, it really points out the way to solve this. Can't thank enough again!

Answer (score 1):

> Will it know that it is a ForeignKey and will create a Person::class automatically?

Absolutely not.

`@ForeignKey` defines a ForeignKey constraint i.e. a rule that says that the column(s) to which the constraint is applied must be a value in the referenced column(s) in the referenced table. The referenced (Parent) tables have to exist and be populated accordingly with values that match the rule.

Type converters are used to convert an unhandled type (not a type this is integer (e.g. Int Long Byte etc), String, decimal number (Float, Double etc) or ByteArray) into a handled type.

As an example  your :-

```
@TypeConverter
fun clientToJson(value: Client?): String? = Gson().toJson(value)
```

would convert a single column such as

```
client: Client
```

from a Client To a JSON String and store that string in the client column. It is not going to split the client into individual values and place them into individual columns.

So with your retrieved JSON String you extract Client objects with embedded Person and Payment Type.

You can only successfully insert the Client if all the Foreign Keys can be met.

So you should probably check that the account_id exists in the account table.
The check that the person_id,account_id exists in the person_table and so on before inserting the Client otherwise the insert will fail.

If the checks fail to identify the rows then you either have to abort or insert the appropriate rows into the tables.

Assuming that your source data is referentially correct. Then you should first extract the highest level parent (Account I believe) inserting them. You can then extract the next level (Person and Payment Type) and insert them and then finally insert the Client. This way the Foreign Keys should exist.

Al alternative would be to turn off Foreign key support and load the data and then turn on Foreign Key support back on. However, if the data is not referentially correct you may encounter Foreign Key constraint conflicts.

e.g. `db.openHelper.writableDatabase.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(false)`

> I've got with the following Client data class which I've turned into a Room @Entity with ForeignKeys:

based upon the JSON you will have issues with the null values unless you ensure that the values are changed to appropriate values.

- e.g. `"updatedAt": null,`  associated with `@ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at") val updatedAt: Date,` unless the TypeConverter returns a non-null value will fail.

> The Room database needs to match the following database structure that has this CREATE TABLE SQL statement:

It does not e.g. you have:-

- `payment_type_id        INTEGER,` but `@ColumnInfo(name = "payment_type_id") val paymentType: Int,` The former does not have the NOT NULL constraint, the latter has an implicit NOT NULL  (`val paymentType: Int?` does not have the implicit NOT NULL)

  - repeated for a number of columns
- `status                 INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,` but `@ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: Int,` the latter does not have the default value using `defaultValue = "1"` in the @ColumnInfo annotation would apply it.

  - However, you cannot use the convenience `@Insert` annotated function as it will ALWAYS supply a value. To have the default value apply you would have to use `@Query("INSERT INTO (csv_of_the_columns_that_are_not_to_have_a_default_value_applied) VALUES ....`
- `CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id, account_id)` but `@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "client_id") val clientId: Int,`. Only the client ID is the Primary Key. You do have `indices = [Index(value = arrayOf("client_id", "account_id"), unique = true)]`. However, you should instead have `primaryKeys = arrayOf("client_id", "account_id")`

**Additional**

Having had a closer look. I believe that your issue is not with type converters nor at present with Foreign keys but with what is an attempt to fit the square peg into the round hole.

Without delving into trying to ignore fields from a JSON perspective a solution to what I believe is the core issue is that the you cannot just fit the Client with Person and Payment objects Embedded into the Client that you want to store.

So first consider this alternative class for the Entity renamed **ClientTable** :-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "client",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Account::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("account_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Person::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("person_id", "account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("person_id", "account_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = PaymentType::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("payment_type_id", "account_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("payment_type_id", "account_id"),
        ),
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(value = arrayOf("client_id", "account_id"), unique = true)
    ]
)
data class ClientTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "client_id") val clientId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "delivery_notes") val deliveryInstructions: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_date") val eventDate: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "monthly_payment_amount") val monthlyPaymentAmount: Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "payment_type_id") val paymentTypeid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "person_id") val personid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "referral_name") val referralName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_date") val startDate: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at") val updatedAt: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "synced_at") val syncedAt: Date,

    /* Not required but may be useful BUT will not be columns in the table */
    @Ignore
    val person: Person,
    @Ignore
    val paymentType: PaymentType
)
```

The only changes are the two additional BUT `@Ignore` annotated **val**s, for the Person and for the PaymentType. The @Ignore results in them not being included as a column in the table. They are there just for demonstration (you might have problems with them being null when extracting the data from the database).

Note that for testing the **PaymentType** is :-

```
@Entity
data class PaymentType(
    @PrimaryKey
    val paymentTypeId: Long? = null,
    val paymentTypeName: String
)
```

and the **Person** is :-

```
@Entity
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey
    val personId: Long,
    val personName: String
)
```

- so the `// Omitted data here` does not cause issues.

Instead of your JSON the following JSON has been used (however it is built on the fly) :-

```
{"clientId":1,"deliveryInstructions":"x","eventDate":"Jan 21, 2022 10:57:59 AM","monthlyPaymentAmount":111.11,"paymentType":{"paymentTypeId":20,"paymentTypeName":"Credit Card"},"person":{"personId":10,"personName":"Bert"},"referralName":"Fred","startDate":"Jan 21, 2022 10:57:59 AM","status":1,"syncedAt":"Jan 21, 2022 10:57:59 AM","updatedAt":"Jan 21, 2022 10:57:59 AM"}
```

A simple not Type Converter json extractor to mimic the API has been added:-

```
class JsonApiExample {
    
     fun testExtractJsonFromString(json: String): Client {
          return Gson().fromJson(json,Client::class.java)
     }
}
```

Now to the other peg The Client with the embedded Person/PaymentType and WITHOUT the personId and paymentTypeId that are not fields in the JSON:-

```
data class Client(
    val clientId: Int,
    val deliveryInstructions: String,
    val eventDate: Date,
    val monthlyPaymentAmount: Float,
    val referralName: String,
    val startDate: Date,
    val status: Int,
    val updatedAt: Date,
    val syncedAt: Date,
    val person: Person,
    val paymentType: PaymentType
) {
    fun getClientAsClientTable(): ClientTable {
        return ClientTable(
            this.clientId,
            this.deliveryInstructions,
            this.eventDate,
            this.monthlyPaymentAmount,
            this.paymentType.paymentTypeId!!.toInt(),
            this.person.personId.toInt(),
            this.referralName,
            this.startDate,
            this.status,
            this.updatedAt,
            this.syncedAt,
            this.person,
            this.paymentType
        )
    }
}
```

**As you can see the important bit is the `getClientAsClientTable` funtion**. This will generate and return a ClientTable Object and effectively make the square peg round to fit.

So testing it, as far as creating a ClientTable that could be inserted (Foreign Keys permitting, which would not be the case due to there being no account_id column in the ClientTable nora field in the Client class) consider :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        /* Create a Client ready to be converted to JSON */
        val clientx = Client(
            clientId = 1,
            deliveryInstructions = "x",
            eventDate = Date(),
            monthlyPaymentAmount = 111.11F, referralName = "Fred", startDate = Date(), status = 1, updatedAt = Date(), syncedAt = Date(),
        Person(10,"Bert"), paymentType = PaymentType(20,"Credit Card"))

        /* Convert the Client to JSON mimicing the API and write it to the log to allow inspection */
        val jsonClientX = Gson().toJson(clientx)
        Log.d("TESTIT",jsonClientX)

        /* Extract the Client from the JSON */
        val clientxrevisited = JsonApiExample().testExtractJsonFromString(jsonClientX)
        /* Extract the ClientTable from the Client */
        val ClientTable = clientxrevisited.getClientAsClientTable()
        /* Allow a Break point to be placed so the results can be inspected*/
        if (1 == 1) {
            Log.d("TESTIT","Testing")
        }
    }
}
```

When run with a BreakPoint :-

[image]

- The ticks are the columns
- The highlighted are the embedded objects from which you would be able to insert or ignore into the respective tables.

  - note that the fields may well be different just id and name were chosen just to demonstrate.

So to **RECAP** two classes; one for the JSON extract/import, and the other for the Entity/Table with a means of turning one into the other.

- A single class may be possible if you can ascertain how to ignore/map JSON fields e.g. perhaps this [How to add and ignore a field for json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892937/how-to-add-and-ignore-a-field-for-json-response)

Comment: Thanks for explaining `ForeignKey` and `TypeConverters`, got both concepts more clear. The `account` table indeed exist when I'm creating the `client` table, however the problem is that the only way to populate the `person`/`payment_type` table is by the data retrieved from the `client` json response. About the null and default values, that was my bad, I'm aware of those null cases and that `defaultValue` doesn't work with `@Insert` that is not an actual problem.

Comment: Another question though, how the `@ColumnInfo(name = "person_id") val person: Int,` will look like if I have `person` of type `Person`(class) instead of `Int`? Will it parse the json correctly? Otherwise, it is the proper way to deserialize the json response first and then insert every nested object separately? There is any 'best' way to do that way?

Comment: @JesusJimenez if you have `person: Person` then you need a TypeConverter in which case you would probably extract the person from the JSON and then the Converter would convert it from the Person into what would probably be a JSON String. It can be done that way. However, then you have issues/complications with the foreign key/referential integrity as you you have the single column containing a String. Personally I would not store JSON strings but have real rather than bloated data. I will, time permitting, try to create an example of how I would do it as an example.